# What is the most reliable method to update a remote Fedora Server installation?

Tags: ssh, fedora, upgrade, remote

For a remote server that can only be accessed via ssh, is [DNF System Upgrade](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade) still the recommended release upgrade method? On a local machine, you can watch the progress of the upgrade after you reboot, but with ssh you would only be able to log back into the server if everything completes successfully.

If not, is there a more reliable method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no more *reliable* method that I've ever found to do a system upgrade.

That said, it can fail if you have third party repositories that have not been updated for the new distribution and are missing packages or have new conflicts. But these problems, if they occur, are shown in the download/transaction test phases. If you get as far as rebooting into the system upgrade, it will complete, barring a power failure or something else catastrophic.

Before you upgrade Fedora, though, you should check the Fedora wiki for an article titled "Common F** bugs", where ** is the Fedora release you are upgrading to. For instance, if you are upgrading from 29 to 30, read [Common F30 bugs](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_F30_bugs) first, to see if any of the problems apply to you, and then either delay your upgrade or apply any workarounds that might be specified.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way to update a remote Fedora server is to it over a safety net:

1. create and verify a backup of remote data you care about
2. establish remote console access, i.e. via some kind of KVM via BMC/iLO/[PiKVM](https://github.com/pikvm/pikvm) or similar

---

Then, it's best if you a local clone of your remote Fedora server where you can test your upgrade steps.

---

Regarding actual upgrade steps you basically have the following choices:

1. simply install the new Fedora version from scratch, run your playbooks and restore your backup
2. use [`dnf system-upgrade`](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/dnf-system-upgrade/) which reboots into a minimal network-less environment for the upgrade
3. use [`fedora-upgrade`](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/upgrading-fedora-online/) or even [dnf directly](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/upgrading-fedora-online/) for upgrading online, i.e. while been able to stay in your - say - tmux'ed ssh session and follow the progress directly

Arguably, the first choice is the most reliable because it's arguably the best tested and least complex one.

Also, with `dnf system-upgrade` you might not even get progress updates when you have console access, e.g. when plymouth isn't installed. (FWIW, still an issue when upgrading from Fedora 35 to 37)

If you really are able to test your upgrade on a local clone then the one that *you* have tested and which succeeded is the most reliable one.